# How do I find the dependency requirements for a source package?

Tags: linux, package-management, compiling, source

If I'm compiling a package from source how do I find the required dependency? 
I notice when compiling Python 3 on Centos7 the only way I could find the required libraries and such was to run the configuration script that came with the tar ball and look for failures.
Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward approach I know of is to use the build requirements which the package maintainers have determined are relevant, on a compatible distribution. Since Python 3 isn’t available in CentOS, you’d have to look at EPEL or some other repository; Fedora hosts [the relevant source package](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/python3).

To list the build dependencies on an RPM-based distribution, look at [the package’s `.spec` file](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/python3/blob/master/f/python3.spec): the build dependencies are listed under `BuildRequires`. For Python 3:

```
BuildRequires: autoconf
BuildRequires: bluez-libs-devel
BuildRequires: bzip2
BuildRequires: bzip2-devel
BuildRequires: desktop-file-utils
BuildRequires: expat-devel

BuildRequires: findutils
BuildRequires: gcc-c++
%if %{with gdbm}
BuildRequires: gdbm-devel
%endif
BuildRequires: glibc-all-langpacks
BuildRequires: glibc-devel
BuildRequires: gmp-devel
BuildRequires: libappstream-glib
BuildRequires: libffi-devel
BuildRequires: libnsl2-devel
BuildRequires: libtirpc-devel
BuildRequires: libGL-devel
BuildRequires: libuuid-devel
BuildRequires: libX11-devel
BuildRequires: ncurses-devel

BuildRequires: openssl-devel
BuildRequires: pkgconfig
BuildRequires: readline-devel
BuildRequires: redhat-rpm-config >= 127
BuildRequires: sqlite-devel
BuildRequires: gdb

BuildRequires: tar
BuildRequires: tcl-devel
BuildRequires: tix-devel
BuildRequires: tk-devel

%if %{with valgrind}
BuildRequires: valgrind-devel
%endif

BuildRequires: xz-devel
BuildRequires: zlib-devel

BuildRequires: /usr/bin/dtrace

# workaround http://bugs.python.org/issue19804 (test_uuid requires ifconfig)
BuildRequires: /usr/sbin/ifconfig

%if %{with rpmwheels}
BuildRequires: python-setuptools-wheel
BuildRequires: python-pip-wheel
%endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Per [rpm.org](https://rpm.org/user_doc/dependencies.html#requires), dependencies are defined in the `.spec` file,

> With this tag a package can require another with the matching name or Provides to be installed (if the package containign the Requires: is going to be installed). This is checked when a new package is installed and if a package with a matching Provides: is removed.

And the example they provide,

```
    Requires: python perl
```

Comment: That doesn’t specify source dependencies, but runtime dependencies.